# How to use object Promise in JSX

Tags: reactjs, promise, axios, jsx

After receiving a Promise object from axios, I want to use it in JSX but error occurs "Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead."

```
//Request.js
import axios from 'axios';

const Request = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'https://ptx.transportdata.tw/MOTC/v2/'
});

export const ScenicSpotRequest = async () => Request.get('Tourism/ScenicSpot?$top=30&$format=JSON').then(response => response.data);

export async function getScenicSpotRequest() {
    try {
        const item = await ScenicSpotRequest();
        // console.log(item);
        return item;
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
}
```

```
//MainScreen.jsx
import { getScenicSpotRequest } from '../Request.js.js';

let test = getScenicSpotRequest().then(result => result[1].Name );

function MainScreen() {

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <Navbar NavbarTitle="ScenicSpot" />
        <InfoCard Name={test} Description="null" Picture="null" />
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default MainScreen;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use useEffect and store it as state in your component (or fetch it somewhere higher in the component hierarchy in an useEffect) and pass it as prop.

```
function MainScreen() {
  
  const [name, setName] = useState(null);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    getScenicSpotRequest().then(result => setName(result[1].Name));
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <Navbar NavbarTitle="ScenicSpot" />
        <InfoCard Name={name} Description="null" Picture="null" />
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default MainScreen;
```

Answer (score 2):

The error occurs because you are passing a `Promise`, not a `jsx` element. To get the jsx element you can create a custom hook to load the component returned by an async function:

Create the custom hook is not required to solve the problem you are facing, but you can reuse the same logic in other parts of your application:

```
const useAsyncComponent(fn) => { //--> fn should be an async function 
   const [Comp, setComp] = useState(null);
   useEffect(()=> {
     fn().then(C => setComp(C));
   });
  return Comp;
}


let test = getScenicSpotRequest().then(result => result[1].Name );

function MainScreen() {
  const Name = useAsyncComponent(()=> test)
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <Navbar NavbarTitle="ScenicSpot" />
        <InfoCard Name={Name} Description="null" Picture="null" />
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I like this answer, it is great!

Comment: `test` isn't a function, it's a promise. It could be made a function for this example to work though.

Comment: yes, you are right, thanks, I will update my answer